# Where is the "compileOnly" task in a gradle project?

Tags: gradle

I created a minimal build.gradle file:

```
 apply plugin: "java"
```

and put a minimal set of Java files in src/main/java.

When I run:

```
gradle dependencies
```

I see various tasks with no dependencies, such as:

```
compileOnly - Compile only dependencies for source set 'main'.
No dependencies
```

However, when I try to run one of them:

```
gradle compileOnly
```

I see:

```
Task 'compileOnly' not found in root project '21-java'.
```

So where is this task and how can I see it?

Comment: `gradle dependencies` lists dependencies, not tasks.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I probably got it totally mixed up... I thought it lists dependencies of tasks.